# Why do I need parseInt() to avoid NaN?

Tags: javascript, parseint

I have a 2D array with 2 values and I want to print the difference with a little message.

```
var array = [[0,2],[3,4]];
console.log(array[0][1]-array[0][0]) //prints '2'
console.log(array[0][1]-array[0][0] + ' is the number') //prints '2 is the number'
console.log('The number is' + array[0][1]-array[0][0]) //prints 'NaN'
console.log('The number is ' + parseInt(array[0][1]-array[0][0], 10)) //prints 'The number is 2'
```

Why do I need to `parseInt()` here to print a message *before* the result, but printing text *after* the result, or just the result on its own, is A-OK?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the `parseInt` makes no difference. It's putting the subtraction in parentheses that matters.

What your code is basically saying is:

```
"The number is" + array[0][1]-array[0][0]
// becomes...
"The number is 2"-array[0][0]
// is cast to...
parseInt("The number is 2")-array[0][0];
// which is...
NaN-0
// or just...
NaN
```

It's all about order of operations.

Comment: I really wish this threw some kind of exception instead of doing type coercion. I don't know how many times I've accidentally concatenated when I meant to add and vise-versa.

Comment: Wow, that's kinda dumb of me, thanks for the answer. I had just assumed that JS would subtract numbers before adding strings. Assumption is the mother of all *%ù£$¨ès...

Comment: Well, I always to parens to ensure things are in the right order. Took me a moment to realise what was going on XD

Answer (score 0):

That occurs because JavaScript follows mathematics order from left to right. Since you started with a string it assumes you are concating strings.

Comment: Except the `-` tries to turn the lhs into a number because `-` isn't defined for strings and the rhs is a number.